# custom editor for list of objects in xctk:PropertyGrid

Tags: wpf, propertygrid

In my WPF project, I'm using a PropertyGrid (from WPF Extended Toolkit) to manage some properties. In particular, I have a list of objects to be managed. By default, PropertyGrid allows user to manage list with a CollectionEditor, in which user can do CRUD operations, but I need a custom editor that allows only to edit objects, without creation or deletion.
The only samples found are those present [here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid) but they seems to explain only how to define a custom editor and change background of a field in grid.

How can I define a brand new custom editor for editing a list of objects?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like:

```
<xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
    <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition TargetProperties="MyProperty">
        <xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            ...
            </DataTemplate>
  </xctk:EditorTemplateDefinition.EditingTemplate>
</xctk:PropertyGrid.EditorDefinitions>
```

From there you can create your own control with a button that pop your editor.